# Regular Expression to filter tracking parameters from URLs in HTML

Tags: php, regex, string, url

I've got strings that contain a tracking-string that i want to remove. Regular expressions seemed to be the best solution but i can't figure a regular expression that will work.

Example URLs:

- http://example.com?tracking=foo
- http://example.com/bar.html?tracking=foo
- http://example.com?tracking=foo&param=baz
- http://example.com/bar.php?param=baz&tracking=foo

`tracking=foo` should be removed where `foo` can be pretty much anything except `&`, URLs without tracking shouldn't be touched.

The best shot i got working is `/(http:\/\/[^?]*?.*)tracking=[^&]*&?(.*?["|\'])/i` but it matches too much with the `[^&]*`-part thus eliminating everything behind the link if there isn't a second parameter on the URL after the tracking string.

And i'm using it like this at the moment `$html` contains the whole html for the page to be output and i want to remove the tracking from all urls within:

```
$html = preg_replace($pattern, '$1$2', $html);
```

So the minimum the $html would contain would be something like this:

```
<body>
 <a href="[one of the examples above]">Some Link</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove the part from the beginning of the string to the end of the tracking string or just the tracking string?

Comment: @Gabber i want to remove the tracking parameter - for example `http://example.com?tracking=foo&param=baz` should become `http://example.com?param=baz`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do this by parsing the URL, using [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url) and [`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse_str). It makes things much easier than using a regular expression.

```
<?php
$params = array();

$url = "http://example.com/bar.php?param=baz&tracking=foo";
$url_parts = parse_url( $url);

parse_str( $url_parts['query'], $params);

// Remove the "tracking" parameter
if( isset( $params['tracking'])) {
    unset( $params['tracking']); 
}
```

Now you just have to rebuild the string using the parts in `$url_parts` and the rest of the params in `$params`. You can do this with [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/http_build_query).

Try something like this, although I haven't tested it so it will need some modifications:

```
$url = $url_parts['scheme'] . '://' . $url_parts['host'] . $url_parts['path'] . '?' . http_build_query( $params);
```

For your specific use-case, I would use PHP's [`DOMDocument`](http://us.php.net/domdocument) class to parse the HTML, then grab all of the URLs from that, then use the above to remove the tracking parameter. However, if you must use a regular expression, you can use a generic regular expression to find just URLs, then apply the above to each URL you find using [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback).

Comment: Perfect answer. Add some comments to your code and I'll have this in my "this is how you should answer" example list :D

Comment: Looks very promising, i'll try this :)

Comment: This is working great and since it's very stable against pretty much any usecase -> perfect :)

Answer (score 2):

```
/tracking=.*?(?=(&|$|\r|"))/
```

Should match all `tracking=foo` variables.  Just replace with empty string.

http://regexr.com?30ofo

Comment: It will match all the rest of the document after the link too: http://regexr.com?30off

Comment: It's close, but it has [some problems](http://regexr.com?30ofl). It's hard to create a single regex that can handle every case correctly.

Comment: http://regexr.com?30ofo How about adding a `"` option like `tracking=.*?(?=(&|$|\r|"))`?

Comment: @nickb You're right, it's hard to create a single regex to handle every single case.  Is something like `tracking=it shouldnt match this it's not a URL` as text even likely? I don't know about the OP's requirements but unless it is, no point in considering an unlikely case.

Answer (score 0):

As a modification to your own regex `(http:\/\/[^?]*?.*)(tracking=[^&]*)(.*)?`

If it matches remove the second group from the string (the one with the tracking)