# Create regex for remove tracking related urls from string

Tags: php, regex

In my working application, I want to remove tracking related code from some text string.as this code has been posted from API which can be added with any tracking code(eg.google tracking url, javascript, facebook tracking URL etc...)

Before inserting into database, I want to skip such URLs from my string, can anyone help me to create regex pattern for it

So far I have tried

```
$pattern = "#(www\.|https?://)?[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]{2,4}\S*#i";
echo preg_replace($pattern, "", $data);
```

Which returns me URL, I want to modify it for getting only tracker related URL which might be checking with any keyword like `track` in URL querystring.

Comment: Modify your question so we can better understand what you really asked for!

Comment: I don't have its fix set but it can be any URL containing words track, might be url?fb=track_me in similar way there should be with google analytics too. though I am not sure what else we can consider

Comment: @anubhava No, it would not works for me, as I told such URLs will be posted via API for which am not sure how many and which kind of rewrite rule we should write, also its un-necessasory to work for these URL rewrite as its non of my use. I just want to get rid of these URL from my string, that is it.

Comment: What do the URLs look like. If you regex is wrong, we can't extract what would be right

Comment: I have HTML string "Lorem ipsum <a href="facebook.com?fb=track_me">.</a> test data, Lorem ipsum" from this I want to remove <a> as it have word "track" so new string would be "Lorem ipsum test data, Lorem ipsum". thats what I want to achieve via regex OR anything in PHP

Comment: you can use the negative lookahead assertion if you are looking for regex

Comment: @anubhava Sadly I can not use DOM as my data posted via standalone API and am just handling it via PHP (get and insert it into database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got some help from stack [Regular Expression to filter tracking parameters from URLs in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297389/regular-expression-to-filter-tracking-parameters-from-urls-in-html)

And I did my code like

```
$pattern = '/(track(ing|er)=.*?)|(track("|_))/'; //Replace any texts containing word like track either in url or QS
$data = preg_replace($pattern, '', $data);

$pattern = '/(utm("|_)+([a-zA-Z]+)=.*?)/'; //Replace any texts followed by "utm_" with blank
$data = preg_replace($pattern, '', $data);
```

So it removed words like `track` from URL, `utm_` from url for google track.